# How to overlay a crosshair

Tags: android, overlay

I have seen many applications where the user touches the screen and the application displays an overlay crosshair view of the point. I would please like to know how this works and how to overlay it such as in the developer option in the phone, where it overlays every screen. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want overlay everything, not just your application, call code like this from service.

```
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.whatToShow, null);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    windowManager.addView(mView, params);
```

And to remove it

```
((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);
```

It requires following line in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Also check out this tutorial
http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Answer (score 1):

You can `inflate` a layout as a View and `add view` to the root view.

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
LayoutParams layoutParamsControl= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
this.addContentView(view, layoutParamsControl);
```